# Setting upper and lower date limits to date picker dialog

Tags: java, android, datepicker, limit

I have created an activity in which there is a field for inserting birth date of the user. I have used a date picker to achieve this.

This is the source code of what I am doing:

```
// onclick dob edittext open date picker dialog
        dob.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
        dob.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                //open date picker
                  showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);

            }
        }); 


//======================For picking birth day==========================
    // Creating dialog
        @Override
        protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            int cyear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int cmonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int cday = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);


            switch (id) {
                case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
                    return new DatePickerDialog(this, mDateSetListener, cyear, cmonth, cday);
            }
            return null;
        }
        private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            // onDateSet method
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
//              String date_selected = String.valueOf(monthOfYear+1)+" /"
//                                    +String.valueOf(dayOfMonth)+" /"
//                                    +String.valueOf(year);

                String date_selected = String.valueOf(dayOfMonth)+" /"
                        +String.valueOf(monthOfYear+1)+" /"
                        +String.valueOf(year);
                //Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Selected Date is ="+date_selected, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                dob.setText(date_selected);
            }
        };
//======================For picking birth day==========================
```

**Now what I want to do is, to limit the date picker to particular year.
Like this:**

```
int maxYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR) - 15; // this year ( 2013 ) - 15 = 1998
                int maxMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                int maxDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

                int minYear = maxYear-49;
                int minMonth = 0; // january
                int minDay = 25;
```

**What should I do to set the above mentioned bounding to the date picker?**

**//----------------Edit---------------------------**

I have done something like this:

```
//======================For picking birth day==========================
    // Creating dialog
        @Override
        protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            maxYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR) - 15; // this year ( 2013 ) - 15 = 1998
            maxMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            maxDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);




            switch (id) {
                case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
                    return new DatePickerDialog(this, mDateSetListener, maxYear, maxMonth, maxDay);
            }
            return null;
        }


        DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {



                int minYear = maxYear-49;
                int minMonth = 0; // january
                int minDay = 25;

            public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,int dayOfMonth) {

                Date current = new Date(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);

                Date minDate = new Date(minYear, minMonth, minDay);
                Date maxDate = new Date(maxYear, maxMonth, maxDay);
                if( current.getTime() < minDate.getTime() )
                {
                    //set to minimum date
                }else if( current.getTime() > maxDate.getTime() )
                {
                    //Set to max Date
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                    int dayOfMonth) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 String date_selected = String.valueOf(dayOfMonth)+" /"
                            +String.valueOf(monthOfYear+1)+" /"
                            +String.valueOf(year);
                    //Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Selected Date is ="+date_selected, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    dob.setText(date_selected);

            }
        };
//======================For picking birth day==========================
```

**This is fixing the upper limit, but the lower limit or the minDate is not getting fixed! What is to be done?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `OnDateChangedListener()` For you `DatePicker` and inside `onDateChanged` function if the date set is greater than the decide limit if so `DatePicker.updateDate(minYear, minMonth, minDay);` use this method to reset it.

```
Date minDate = new Date(1990, 10, 25);
Date maxDate = new Date(2013, 4, 15);



OnDateChangedListener listener = new OnDateChangedListener() {

    @Override
    public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
            int dayOfMonth) {

        Date current = new Date(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);

        if( current.getTime() < minDate.getTime() )
        {
            //set to minimum date
        }else if( current.getTime() > maxDate.getTime() )
        {
            //Set to max Date
        }

    }
};
YourDatePicker.init(2013, 4, 15, listener);
```

Comment: CAN YOU PLEASE EXPLAIN A BIT MORE ELABORATELY?

Comment: @kittu88 would you also want RajeshCP go to your pc and write the code for you?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza No I did not mean that, I wanted to know where to put the  public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
            int dayOfMonth) and what to do with public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth)

Comment: Now this would be the maximum I can provide you....I haven't tested the code but hope this will help

Comment: @RajeshCP please check edit, of my question if you do not mind!