# DatePickerDialog setMaxDate show one month and one day additional

Tags: java, android, datepicker

I have a dialog dAte picker like this:

```
                     public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        int yy = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int mm = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int dd = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        DatePickerDialog datePicker = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, yy, mm, dd);
        datePicker.getDatePicker().setCalendarViewShown(false);

        datePicker.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(new Date().getTime());

        datePicker.setTitle("RENTRE TA DATE DE NAISSANCE.");

        return datePicker;
    }
```

[image: ...]

We can see my problem On the image the date of today is 27 juil 2014 i want that date picker stop at this date and don't show 28 aout
Thank's for your help

Comment: is the `setMaxDate()` not working at all, or does it stop you going past the 28th instead of the 27th like you expect?

Comment: Today is August 28 and not July 27. What's the problem?

Comment: maybe it can be useful
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16029361/setting-upper-and-lower-date-limits-to-date-picker-dialog

Comment: @Dreagen
the picture is from yesthirday it was 27 that's why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add 1 day and 1 month to your calender instance. And pass it to `setMaxDate()`

```
    // Set calendar to 1 day next from today
    calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
    // Set calendar to 1 month next
    calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
    datePicker.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(calendar.getTimeInMillis());
```

---

So your method will look like

```
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    int yy = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int mm = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int dd = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    DatePickerDialog datePicker = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this,
            yy, mm, dd);
    datePicker.getDatePicker().setCalendarViewShown(false);
    // Set calendar to 1 day next from today
    calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
    // Set calendar to 1 month next
    calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
    datePicker.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(calendar.getTimeInMillis());

    datePicker.setTitle("RENTRE TA DATE DE NAISSANCE.");

    return datePicker;
}
```